# Date range set operations

Tags: c#, sql, sqlite, date, system.data.sqlite

I've got some data in a series of SQLite databases with various related tables. Each table has a start and an end date column representing the date range for which each record is valid. The SQLite databases are primarily accessed using C# and the System.Data.SQLite library.

I'm looking to be able to queries such as joins where date ranges either overlap, or do not overlap. I've found joining the data where they do overlap simple enough:

```sql
SELECT a.field, max(a.start, b.start) as start, min(a.end, b.end) as end
FROM a
INNER JOIN b
ON a.field = b.field AND NOT(a.start > b.end OR b.start > a.end);
```

But I am not sure how to get the time periods of a where it does not have a matching b. It's easy to get records in a where there is no overlap:

```sql
SELECT a.field, a.start, a.end
FROM a
LEFT JOIN b
ON a.field = b.field AND NOT(a.start > b.end OR b.start > a.end)
WHERE b.field is NULL;
```

But what about where they overlap, or b splits a into two records? Showing the date ranges as timelines, how do I get `c` in the `a-b=c` relationship shown below (the lines represent the date ranges of individual records within the tables `a` and `b`, and the result set `c`)

```
a: |-----------------|    |--------|  |--------||-----|
b:        |---|                  |--------|
c: |-----|     |-----|    |-----|          |---||-----|
```

Or better yet, is there some library, extension, command I don't know about, or other solution that can be used to simplify these queries? Something that can handle the messy date-range operations for me?

Comment: have tried something like this: WHERE condition BETWEEN lower_range AND upper_range

Comment: [SQL:2011](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL:2011) looks promising. Maybe I'll just have to brush up on my C and add some of those features to SQLite myself.

Answer (score 2):

A couple of pointers:

- Make sure your values are either are timestamps based on UTC, or whole calendar dates only.  This is to avoid issues of Time Zones and Daylight Saving Time.
- Use half-open intervals, `[start, end)`.  This will avoid the problem of two adjacent ranges containing the same value.  In other words:

  - `start <= value < end`
  - `start <= value && end > value`
- You might consider using [Noda Time](http://nodatime.org).  It has an `Interval` type that represents this well.  But, it doesn't currently have very many operations defined.
- You might also consider using the [Time Period Library for .NET](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/168662/Time-Period-Library-for-NET), which has a *vast* number of operations defined.  Just be careful that all of your `DateTime` values that you use with it have `DateTimeKind.Utc` for their `.Kind` value.  If you try to use Local kinds, it will not behave properly.  In other words, don't pass `DateTime.Now`.
- Of course, there is no need to use *any* library.  You can always define your own struct or class to contain the range.  There isn't anything built in for this, no.
- The query you wrote is good for detecting overlaps, but you might want to simplify it slightly:

  Instead of this: `NOT(a.start > b.end OR b.start > a.end)`
  Do this:  `a.start < b.end AND b.start < a.end`

  That is logically equivalent, but will perform slightly better as a query.

I'm not sure how to *directly* answer your questions though.  It's not quite clear what you are asking.  Specifically, in that last example, do the two ranges of `c` already exist in the table and you want to return them? Or are you wanting to *construct* them from the calculation between a and b?  If the latter, it's probably best to do that part in C# and not in SQL.

Comment: By "how do I get c (two records) in the a-b=c" I mean how do I construct c from a and b. How do I do a query to find the date ranges of a that do not intersect with b for some arbitrary relationship between a and b. When I say "two records" I mean that c could represent two or fewer records depending if b is contained in a, partially overlaps with a or completely covers a.

Comment: You can construct `c` in your C# code. I wouldn't attempt that in SQL.  But for the query, what are the input parameters?  Do you want *all* date ranges that have no overlaps? Or are you passing a single date or a start and end date?

Comment: I'm looking for a general case here. In other words, in my input data a may represent one or more non-intersecting date ranges, and b may represent zero or more non-intersecting date ranges. I want to find the zero or more non-intersecting ranges c that result from removing all the overlapping ranges between a and b.

Comment: But surely the range is still constrained by some minimum start and maximum end dates, yes?  Otherwise you would have to retrieve all data in your database to do this - which I'm guessing is a lot.

Comment: Well... if the question I'm building a query to answer is "find all records in A that have no related records in B" then I guess the time constraint would be the maximum and minimum dates for records in A? I'm not sure how that's relevant, but does that help? Like I said I'm looking for a general case. This isn't for a single query or operation. There are many different questions I need to answer from this data, some are specific to points in time (very easy to write queries for), others are for specific intervals of time, and some are general, for all/any time.

Comment: What's confusing me is that in some cases we're talking about `a` and `b` as if they are individual ranges, but we are writing queries against `a` and `b` as if they are different tables that contain multiple ranges.  Can you help straighten that out? Then I'm sure I can answer you more directly.

Comment: Sorry, I thought that was clear enough. `a` and `b` are tables. I gave a simplified example to illustrate the sort of operation I was trying to do, where both `a` and `b` were single record examples. I'll edit the question to try to make it clearer.

Answer (score 0):

Using the [Time Period Library for .NET](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/168662/Time-Period-Library-for-NET) you can read the time periods into a collection and apply the **TimeGapCalculator**, **TimePeriodCombiner** or the **TimePeriodSubtractor** utilities to evaluate the desired gaps and overlaps.